# Desfire - command for Ndef Application : get security exception

Tags: java, nfc, mifare

I send the following command to a Desfire tag to detect a Ndef Application :

```
new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, new byte[]{(byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0x85, 0x01, 0x01}
```

I can't get any response because I get the following security exception : SCARD_W_RESET_CARD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are doing is Selecting Application by AID.
Theoretically if card cannot find this AID i.e. there is not such application on the card it should return Status Word 6A82. If it is not the case most probably Card or Reader are faulty.
I don't know details of your source code snippet. Could you please give more details?

Comment: Thanks, yes the problem seems to come from the tag reader I use (Acr 122).  Same command with android works fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have set P2 to 0 (requesting to have File Control Info returned in the response), while Le is absent. This is not compliant to the latest version of ISO 17816-4. Try setting Le to 0, then the select command will be compliant to the Type 4 Tag version 2 specification.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem don't seem to come from the APDU command, I test with the roof byte[] without using the CommandAPDU and the le byte : I get the same error. (For me the COmmandAPDU add automatically the le byte)